# PHP MySQL prepared statement not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently stumped at the moment as to why a statement I have prepared with PHP is not working properly.

The code is as such:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM mail WHERE userID = ? AND opened = 0');
    if($stmt)
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$_SESSION['id']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        $msgs = $stmt->num_rows;

        $stmt->close();
    }

    if($msgs > 0)
    {
        $msgs = '<span style="color: yellow;">'.$result->num_rows.'</span>';
    }

    echo ' <a href="mail?id='.$_SESSION['id'].'"><img src="img/'.$mailico.'" alt="'.$mailstat.'" /> ('.$msgs.')</a>';
```

Basically, it is supposed to check the database for the table "mail" and see if any PM's have been sent to the logged in user that have not already been opened, and if so, display how many new messages the user has in parenthesis next the the mail icon.

The problem is that when I have an unopened message in the table for that user, it won't update the new message field with the number of message, and is blank (no number at all).

I checked for mysql errors with mysqli_error($db); but nothing came back.

What am I missing, or does it just hate me?

Comment: Where do you declare $result? I see that there is $msgs = $stmt->num_rows, then you check the value of it and then declare new value in if statement. Is the logos correct? BTW. I always use try...catch to get exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$msgs = '<span style="color: yellow;">'.$result->num_rows.'</span>';
```

to

```
$msgs = '<span style="color: yellow;">' . $msgs . '</span>';
```

Comment: This one was the issue. I had previously tried to do a basic $sql = <statement) query, and declared $result to run it, but forgot to change that line when I switched to $stmt.

A oversight on my part. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Are there errors in the php log? I think the issue might be because of the use of `$_SESSION['id']` directly - try creating as a variable first like

```
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
$stmt->bind_param('s',$id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The bind_param() needs name of parameter or index of a parameter. So you should write code like this

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM mail WHERE userID = ? AND opened = 0');
$stmt->bind_param(1,$_SESSION['id']);
```

or

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM mail WHERE userID = :user_id AND opened = 0');
$stmt->bind_param(':user_id',$_SESSION['id']);
```

Comment: This is mysqli, not pdo. So named placeholders are not supported - and even in pdo, you can use unnamed placeholders (i.e. `?`)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM mail WHERE userID = ? AND opened = 0');
    if($stmt)
    {
        $stmt->bind_param(1,$_SESSION['id']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $msgs = $stmt->num_rows;
        $stmt->close();
    }

    if($msgs > 0)
    {
        $msgs = '<span style="color: yellow;">'.$result->num_rows.'</span>';
    }

    echo ' <a href="mail?id='.$_SESSION['id'].'"><img src="img/'.$mailico.'" alt="'.$mailstat.'" /> ('.$msgs.')</a>';
```